# Uploaded File Storage/Retrieval

Tags: file-upload, autoscaling

I am developing a web application that needs to store uploaded files - images, pdfs, etc. I need this to be secure and to scale - I don't have a finite number of uploads to plan for. From my research, the best practice seems to be storing files in the private file system, storing paths and meta data in the database, and serving through an authenticated script.

My question is where should these files be stored?

I can't store them on the web servers because I have more than 1, would be worried about disk space, and don't want the performance hit from replication.

Should they be programmatically uploaded to a CDN? Should I spin up a file server/cluster to handle this?

Is there a standard way for securely storing/retrieving a large number of files for web applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My question is where should these files be stored?"
I would suggest using a dedicated storage server or cloud service such as Amazon AWS.  It is secure and completely scalable.  That is how it is usually done these days.

"Should they be programmatically uploaded to a CDN?" - yes, along with a matching db entry of some sort for retrieval.

"Should I spin up a file server/cluster to handle this?" - you could.  I would suggest one of the many cloud storage services though.

"Is there a standard way for securely storing/retrieving a large number of files for web applications?"  Yes.  Uploading files and info via web or mobile app (.php, rails, .net, etc) where the app uploads to storage area (not located in public directory) and then inserts file info into a database.